# Constructing combined json from records in CLOB(Oracle)

Tags: java, json, oracle

I have json stored in CLOB (Oracle)
actual json strucuture is very complicated and large but for the question let say

```
{"id":"1", "name":"a"}
```

On my stored procedure call(getById) to Oracle, I am getting list of above json (SYS_REFCURSOR)
now i need to build new json like below

```
{ "results" : {
   "getById" : [
      {"id":"1", "name":"a"},
      {"id":"2", "name":"b"},
      {"id":"3", "name":"c"}
    ],
   "result_count" : 3
   },
   "Status":"SUCCESS"
   }
}
```

If I don't need to know the json structure of the returned json from stored procedure and just pass to client with above json format, what would be the best approach?
If i save the returned json into String and construct as part of getById tag, it treats as one value and break json.
I can build this using ObjectMapper but in this case i need to create object class for {"id":"1", "name":"a"} in Java and i need to change this when json format gets changed which I don't want to do if I can avoid.

Please, guide me for any better solution.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started

```
SQL> create table t ( c clob );

Table created.

SQL> insert into t
  2  select '{"id":"'||rownum||'", "name":"a"}'
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 10;

10 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> declare
  2    l_results json_object_t := json_object_t();
  3    l_elem    json_array_t := JSON_ARRAY_T();
  4  begin
  5    for i in ( select c from t )
  6    loop
  7       l_elem.append(json_object_t(i.c));
  8    end loop;
  9    l_results.put('getById',l_elem);
 10    dbms_output.put_line(l_results.stringify);
 11
 12  end;
 13  /
{"getById":[{"id":"1","name":"a"},{"id":"2","name":"a"},{"id":"3","name":"a"},{"id":"4","name":"a"},{"id":"5","name":"a"},{"id":"6
","name":"a"},{"id":"7","name":"a"},{"id":"8","name":"a"},{"id":"9","name":"a"},{"id":"10","name":"a"}]}

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```